# Is there any way to clear subscription to an event in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, events, subscription

In C#, I took the habit on clearing every subscriptions to my custom events in `Dispose()` to avoid memory leaks of subscribers forgetting to unsubscribe from my events.

It was very simple to do, simply by calling `MyEvent = null` since the C# compiler automatically generates a delegate field. Unfortunately in VB.NET, there seems to be no simple way to do this. The only solution I came up with was to write a `Custom Event`, adding custom add and remove handlers calling `Delegate.Combine` / `Delegate.Remove`, basically what the C# compiler does. But having to do this for every event just to be able to clear the subscriptions seems a little 'overkill' to me.

Does anyone have another idea to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's exactly the same in VB.Net. The compiler [automatically creates a delegate field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711966(VS.71).aspx) for each event, just like the C# compiler, but in VB the field is hidden. However you can access the variable from your code - it's always named XXXEvent, where XXX is the event name.

So you can easily clear subscriptions to the event, just like in C#:

```
Public Class Class1
  Implements IDisposable
  Event MyEvent()

  Sub Clear() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Me.MyEventEvent = Nothing ' clear the hidden variable '
  End Sub
End Class
```

I'm also thinking it should be possible to use reflection to automatically find all the hidden delegate variables, and clear them. Then they don't have to be listed in the `Clear` method.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that documentation section, very helpful. As using reflection, that's seem quite heavy just to set some variables to null; but quite useful to assert at debug time that every field was correctly set to null.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there could be a general purpose method ClearAllSubscriptions that uses reflection to deal with any type: then all you need in your Clear method is `ClearAllSubscriptions Me`

Answer (score 0):

I've got only vague knowledge of VB.NET, but what about AddHandler / RemoveHandler?

Comment: AddHandler/RemoveHandler is the VB.NET equivalent of += and -= in C#. Since I don't know every subscriber (unless I make the event custom) I can't RemoveHandler each one.